# Javascript for vertical text scroll breaking page layout

Tags: javascript, css

My code was validating perfectly and looked great, until I added a vertical text scroller script to the left most floating div in a 3 column css layout. Adding the script causes content below the script to repeat - both text and backgrounds - in several modern browsers (IE 6.0 - 7.0 - 8.0, Opera 8 - 9- 10). Safari and Firefox are OK.

The script is JavaScript, and you add it by placing this code where you want the scroller to appear on the page, in my case inside the 3rd floated div:

```
<script language="javascript" src="myvsbody.js" type="text/javascript">
            </script>
```

There is also an onload property that goes in the body tag:

```
<body onload="vsscrollstart();">
```

and a parameters script in the head area that formats the scroller box:

```
<script language="javascript" src="myvsparmsg.js" type="text/javascript">
```

The script is supposed to be cross browser compatible.

Here is the web page online and links to the code:

```
http://www.jillknobloch.com/new/
../new/main.css
../new/myvsbody.js
../new/myvsparmsg.js
```

I thought I had hold of a bad script, so I tried another one and the same layout problem reoccurred!! So I think it's my XHTML/CSS. Also because the script does work across all browsers when used in this template, which I got from template world and loaded on my site:

> www.jillknobloch.com/test5/

*I HAVE SPENT ABOUT 48 HOURS STARRING AT THE TEMPLATE WORLD PAGE TRYING TO FIND THE DIFFERENCE BETWEEN THAT CODE AND MINE AND I CANNOT FIGURE OUT WHY THE TEXT SCROLL SCRIPT WORKS ON THAT PAGE AND NOT ON MINE.*

I am a new Javascipt programmer, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Jill Knobloch

Comment: So you've narrowed it down to the javascript. Unfortunately, those scripts are compressed making it very difficult to do any troubleshooting. If you have access to the uncompressed scripts that would help alot.

Also, calling any IE a modern browser is a stretch ;)

Comment: It's awful nice of you to refer to IE6 as a "modern browser."

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in IE8.

Comment: I just tried it in Opera 10 and IE 6, and it looked fine.  I didn't see anything being repeated.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Thanks everyone,
No solution yet. I was using Browser Shots, and that's where I saw that it was repeating content in IE 6, 7, 8 and Opera - maybe Browser Shots isn't always right?

Also I uncompressed the script at http://www.jillknobloch.com/new/myvsbody.js

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, I would suggest using virtual machines, rather than services like browsershots, to test cross-browser compatibility.  THat way, you can actually interact with the site, instead of just look at it, which is critical for debugging javascript 'issues' with IE.  Check out http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en for virtual machines that run various versions of IE.

Comment: Thanks I will check out microsoft.com/downloads/... 
:-)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything wrong in the problematic browsers you mentioned, but the HTML validation error is caused by the `language` attribute on the script tags.  It is not needed.  Try this instead:

```
<script src="myvsbody.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will take out that language part. And thanks for testing in the other browsers. 

Not sure why Browser Shots was showing that the site was broken. A little confused now, I will try checking it on virtual machines as pkaeding suggested above.

:-)

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure why browser shots would show something different either, but it is possible that they aren't running the javascript, or something like that. There could be good security arguments for not running javascript in a setting like that. In any case, the virtual machines are a much more authentic representation of how your site will look & function.

Comment: By the way, if you feel that this (or any) answer solves your problem, you may want to consider marking it as the 'accepted' answer, by clicking the check mark next to the answer.  Thanks!